# Deleting Customer and Order Data from WooCommerce SQL Database: Direct Method via SQL File Access

Tags: sql, woocommerce, terminal

I am seeking assistance on how to delete all customer and order data from a WooCommerce SQL database. I have come across a method that can be used directly in phpMyAdmin with the following code:

```
DELETE wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_woocommerce_order_items, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items ON wp_posts.ID = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = "shop_order"
AND wp_posts.post_date < '2023-06-28';
```

However, I am wondering if there is a method to achieve this directly on the SQL file itself. The SQL file is located in a folder on my Linux computer, and I access it through the terminal. I would like to end up with an SQL file that does not contain any customer data, which I can then import into a database.

Thank you in advance for any ideas or suggestions!